# Background color for text labels?

Tags: geoserver

Is it possible to render a background color for text labels in geoserver? My current style is this:

```
  <TextSymbolizer>
    <Label>
      <ogc:PropertyName>fahrznr</ogc:PropertyName>
    </Label>
    <Font>
      <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
    </Font>
    <LabelPlacement>
      <PointPlacement>
        <AnchorPoint>
          <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
          <AnchorPointY>-1</AnchorPointY>
        </AnchorPoint>
      </PointPlacement>
    </LabelPlacement>
  </TextSymbolizer>
```

Which produces the following text (with transparent background):
[image]

But what I want is the following (with green background):
[image]

Is this somehow possible with geoserver style? I tried

```
<CssParameter name="fill">#00FF00</CssParameter>
<CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</CssParameter>
```

And

```
<CssParameter name="background">#00FF00</CssParameter>
```

Both do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GeoServer's SLD you can specify a `graphic` element for your label. You will also want to set [`graphic-resize`](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#graphic-resize) and [`graphic-margin`](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#graphic-margin) elements to control how the graphic fits your label.

So your SLD will become something like:

```
 <TextSymbolizer>
    <Label>
      <ogc:PropertyName>fahrznr</ogc:PropertyName>
    </Label>
    <Font>
      <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
    </Font>
    <LabelPlacement>
      <PointPlacement>
        <AnchorPoint>
          <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
          <AnchorPointY>-1</AnchorPointY>
        </AnchorPoint>
      </PointPlacement>
    </LabelPlacement>
    <Graphic>
       <Mark>
         <WellKnownName>Square</WellKnownName>
         <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#00FF00</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
         <Size>10</Size>
       </Mark>

    </Graphic>
    <VendorOption name="graphic-resize">stretch</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="graphic-margin">2</VendorOption>
  </TextSymbolizer>
```